# Autofilter error: the object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I've seen this error message on other posts but none matched my situation.

I have a few AutoFilter functions done one after the other checking if the target cell is empty and moving on if it is.

The code runs until the 6th iteration wherein I get the error

> "the object invoked has disconnected from its clients"

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton49_Click()
'
Dim Wsdnd As Worksheet

Set Wsdnd = Sheets("DO NOT DELETE")

Dim A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9, A10, ... (more variables) As Range

Set A3 = Wsdnd.Range("BD3")
Set A4 = Wsdnd.Range("BD4")
Set A5 = Wsdnd.Range("BD5")
Set A6 = Wsdnd.Range("BD6")
Set A7 = Wsdnd.Range("BD7")
Set A8 = Wsdnd.Range("BD8")
... (More variables)
'
    Wsdnd.Range("BC3:BE50").Calculate          'Refreshing "Category", "Apply All Data", "Match Lookup Value" Lists on DO NOT DELETE sheet
    Application.Calculation = xlManual         'Restarts manual calculations only for workbook speed
'
'Filter #4
    If Not IsEmpty(A6.Value) Then
        Sheets("Database").Range("B$24:BL$71499").AutoFilter Field:=WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("DO NOT DELETE").Range("BE6"), _
          Worksheets("Database").Range("B23:BL23"), 0), Criteria1:=A6.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Else
    End If
'
'Filter #5
    If Not IsEmpty(A7.Value) Then
        Sheets("Database").Range("B$24:BL$71499").AutoFilter Field:=WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("DO NOT DELETE").Range("BE7"), _
          Worksheets("Database").Range("B23:BL23"), 0), Criteria1:=A7.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Else
    End If
'
'Filter #6
    If Not IsEmpty(A8.Value) Then
        Sheets("Database").Range("B$24:BL$71499").AutoFilter Field:=WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("DO NOT DELETE").Range("BE8"), _
          Worksheets("Database").Range("B23:BL23"), 0), Criteria1:=A8.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Else
    End If
'
'... Filters continue
```

The data being called in the variables is:
String ("F8442")
String ("Unspecified")
Integer ("345")

I wasn't sure if the data type above would be an issue since they were referring to a cell and many times the cell value can change from text to a number and vice versa.

---

I had left out `Range.Calculate` and `Application.Calculation = xlManual` as I didn't think they would have an affect on the code but added them here as I'm not sure. When taken out of the code it gives the error at the same location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Filter a Worksheet

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton49_Click()
    FilterWorksheet
End Sub

Sub FilterWorksheet()
    Const ProcName As String = "FilterWorksheet"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
 
    Const sName As String = "DO NOT DELETE"
    Const srgAddress As String = "BC3:BE50" ' ?
    Const srrgAddress As String = "BD4:BD10" ' resize
    Const scOffset As Long = 1 ' ('BE4:BE10')
    
    Const dName As String = "Database"
    Const drgAddress As String = "B23:BL71499"
     
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(srgAddress)
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = sws.Range(srrgAddress)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    If dws.AutoFilterMode Then dws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(drgAddress)
    Dim dhrg As Range: Set dhrg = drg.Rows(1)

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    
    srg.Calculate 'Refreshing "Category", "Apply All Data", "Match Lookup Value"

    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim sValue As Variant
    Dim dField As Variant
        
    For Each sCell In srrg.Cells
        sValue = sCell.Value
        If Not IsError(sValue) Then
            If Len(CStr(sValue)) > 0 Then
                dField = Application _
                    .Match(sCell.Offset(, scOffset).Value, dhrg, 0)
                If IsNumeric(dField) Then
                    drg.AutoFilter Field:=dField, Criteria1:=sValue
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next sCell
    
SafeExit:
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub
```

Comment: VBasic2008, wow, that's... amazing, thank you so much for taking the time to write/adapt this for the code I had originally. Lot's of (what seems to my novice self) good practices there that I'll keep in mind moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems that the problem was twofold, one that the Criteria needed to be a string and it was getting an integer back and secondly Operator:=xlFilterValues being placed after instructions with only a single variable was looked poorly upon by the excel gods.

In my case at least, this isn't a problem anymore. Hopefully this information helps someone else in the future!

Revised code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton49_Click()
'
Dim Wsdnd As Worksheet

Set Wsdnd = Sheets("DO NOT DELETE")

Dim A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9, A10, ... (more variables) As Range

A4 = Wsdnd.Range("BD4").Value
A5 = Wsdnd.Range("BD5").Value
A6 = Wsdnd.Range("BD6").Value
A7 = Wsdnd.Range("BD7").Value
A8 = Wsdnd.Range("BD8").Value
... (More variables)
'
    Wsdnd.Range("BC3:BE50").Calculate          'Refreshing "Category", "Apply All Data", "Match Lookup Value" Lists on DO NOT DELETE sheet
        Application.Calculation = xlManual      'Restarts manual calculations only for workbook speed
'
'Filter #4
    If Not IsEmpty(A6) Then
        Sheets("Database").Range("B$24:BL$71499").AutoFilter Field:=WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("DO NOT DELETE").Range("BE6"), _
                Worksheets("Database").Range("B23:BL23"), 0), Criteria1:=A6
            Else
    End If
'
'Filter #5
    If Not IsEmpty(A7) Then
        Sheets("Database").Range("B$24:BL$71499").AutoFilter Field:=WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("DO NOT DELETE").Range("BE7"), _
                Worksheets("Database").Range("B23:BL23"), 0), Criteria1:=A7
            Else
    End If
'
'Filter #6
    If Not IsEmpty(A8) Then
        Sheets("Database").Range("B$24:BL$71499").AutoFilter Field:=WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("DO NOT DELETE").Range("BE8"), _
                Worksheets("Database").Range("B23:BL23"), 0), Criteria1:=A8
            Else
    End If
```